# Python: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Just been testing around trying to get web scraping to work but this is bugging me. This is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=pc&_sacat=0')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
posts = soup.find_all(class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')

with open('ebay.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
    headers = ['Title', 'Price', 'Link']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for post in posts:
        price = post.find(class_='s-item__price').get_text().replace('\n', '')
        title = post.find(class_='s-item__title').get_text().replace('\n', '')
        link = post.find('a')['href']
        csv_writer.writerow([title, price, link])
```

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/WebScraping.py", line 8, in <module>
    posts = soup.find_all(class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Tried to find other solutions but can't find any that work for me. The code works but only for a third of the page.

Comment: you are using wrong part of `soup.find_all(class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')`, change it to be `soup.find_all("div", class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')` that's why you getting `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to encode the `soup` object which produces `bytes` object representation of that object and there is no method named `find_all` in `bytes` object.

Replace:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser').encode("utf-8")
```

**With:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
```

Comment: ```File "path/WebScraping.py", line 19, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow([title, price, link])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2714' in position 42: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: Well i've tried running your code and there is no such error occurring.

Comment: that's not very helpful. I don't understand what is wrong then. What does your C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py look like?

Comment: I think you should try this `open('ebay.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8")`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: it removed that error but gave me this one: ```File "path/WebScraping.py", line 16, in <module>
    price = post.find(class_='s-item__price').get_text().replace('\n', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'```

Comment: It did help though. Now it displays more that half of the page.

Comment: Well this seems to be problem with the encoding, you might want to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text.encode("utf-8"),'html.parser')`.

Comment: That definitely helped. It displayed all of them other than the last one without errors! Thank you

Comment: @Ksnakes0 check my answer to understand why you were getting errors from the beginning .

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv



def Main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    names = [item.text for item in soup.findAll(
        "h3", class_="s-item__title")]
    prices = [item.text for item in soup.findAll(
        "span", class_="s-item__price")]
    urls = [item.get("href")
            for item in soup.findAll("a", class_="s-item__link")]
    with open("result.csv", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        wrriter = csv.writer(f)
        wrriter.writerow(["Name", "Price", "Url"])
        data = zip(names, prices, urls)
        wrriter.writerows(data)


Main("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=pc&_sacat=0")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/adbcfc909eb1c3f6390364990961bcdf/result.csv)

> Note: You were using `soup.find_all(class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')` instead of `soup.find_all("div", class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')`

That's why you received `AttributeError`

And regarding `UnicodeEncodeError`, I believe that you are using `Windows` where the default encoding is `cp1252` which will not be able to read `Unicode` such as .

try :

```py
print(\u2714)
```

Output should be: ✔ but your system will give `UnicodeEncodeError`.

So you've 2 options, or to change your system `locale` settings,

open [cmd.exe](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm) then type `chcp`, i believe that you will get `437` which is `United States`.

Now you need to change it to be `chcp 65001` which is `UTF-8` support. [Ref..](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)

or to encode the `csv` with `utf-8` with `encoding="UTF-8"`